# Find all groups of contiguous timestamp and assigns a unique id to each group in a data frame

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, pandas-groupby

I want to write a function that assigns a unique ID to all groups of contiguous timeframe, where 'contiguous' means all the observation within the group are no more that 'max_time_gap' seconds apart.

e.g:
def assign_groups(df, max_time_gap, group_col_name):

Where df is the input data as a pandas data frame, max_time_gap is the maximum time in seconds between timestamps, and group_col_name is the destination column containing the assigned group ids.

Most of data appear at regular intervals, but there are some gaps.

|  | clients | connections | grants | bytes | updates | writes | timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 12333 | 322 | 23323 | 2433 | 6543 | 2019-04-18 21:06:07.260973 |
| 1 | 122 | 8777 | 766 | 4556 | 8755 | 766.4 | 2019-04-18 21:06:07.344215 |
| 2 | 655 | 75566 | 4567 | 9877.6 | 56.6 | 778 | 2019-04-18 21:06:07.436656 |
| 3 | 454 | 453 | 32.5 | 4553 | 344 | 3422 | 2019-04-18 21:06:07.525223 |
| 4 | 3222 | 113 | 342 | 5644 | 4566 | 233.3 | 2019-04-18 21:06:09.622103 |
| 5 | 3122 | 113 | 42 | 2644 | 4536 | 333.3 | 2019-04-18 21:06:10.622103 |
| 6 | 3222 | 133 | 342 | 5644 | 4516 | 133.3 | 2019-04-18 21:06:10.722103 |

...

I tried some of pandas groupby operations such as 'df.groupby.Datetime.diff.gt(pd.Timedelta(seconds=max_time_gap)...'.
They did not work.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: what is your expected output from the given dataframe?

Comment: @Anurag Danas, I believe the question wants the input df with an additional column containing a group ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way:

**1) Convert the column `timestamp` to datetime format if not already in that format**

```
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'])
```

**2) Define the function as follows:**

Use [`pd.Grouper()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html) for grouping by the `max_time_gap` intervals.  Then, take the group numbers by [`GroupBy.ngroup()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.ngroup.html) and re-serialize these group numbers by  [`.cumsum()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) when the group number changes.

```
def assign_groups(df, max_time_gap, group_col_name):
    df['_temp'] = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='timestamp', freq=max_time_gap, origin='start')).ngroup()
    df[group_col_name] = df['_temp'].ne(df['_temp'].shift()).cumsum()
    df.drop('_temp', axis=1, inplace=True)
```

`max_time_gap` is defined in format the same as the *frequency string* of [`pd.Grouper()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html), e.g. `'1s'` for 1 second;  `'500ms'` for 500 milliseconds, etc.    You can refer to the [official document](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html) for more example of this string and also the [`Offset aliases`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#offset-aliases) for more frequency options (e.g. `'H'` for hourly frequency, `'T'` for minutely frequency, etc.)

**3) Call the function as follows:**

```
assign_groups(df, '500ms', 'Group_ID')     # for 500 milli-seconds max_time_gap
```

**Result:**

**New column of `Group_ID` at the right of the dataframe.**

```
print(df)

   clients  connections  grants    bytes  updates  writes                  timestamp  Group_ID
0        0        12333   322.0  23323.0   2433.0  6543.0 2019-04-18 21:06:07.260973         1
1      122         8777   766.0   4556.0   8755.0   766.4 2019-04-18 21:06:07.344215         1
2      655        75566  4567.0   9877.6     56.6   778.0 2019-04-18 21:06:07.436656         1
3      454          453    32.5   4553.0    344.0  3422.0 2019-04-18 21:06:07.525223         1
4     3222          113   342.0   5644.0   4566.0   233.3 2019-04-18 21:06:09.622103         2
5     3122          113    42.0   2644.0   4536.0   333.3 2019-04-18 21:06:10.622103         3
6     3222          133   342.0   5644.0   4516.0   133.3 2019-04-18 21:06:10.722103         3
```

### Edit

If need more accurate grouping, we need to reset the origin / base time for each group to use the first timestamp of the group.  As such, we could define the function as follows:

```
def assign_groups(df, max_time_gap, group_col_name):
    max_time_gap_ns = pd.to_timedelta(max_time_gap) / pd.Timedelta(nanoseconds=1)

    last_time = df['timestamp'][0]
    gap_tot_time_ns = 0
    group_no = 1
    
    for i, t in df['timestamp'].iteritems():
        gap_tot_time_ns += (t - last_time) / pd.Timedelta(nanoseconds=1)
        if gap_tot_time_ns > max_time_gap_ns:
            group_no +=1
            gap_tot_time_ns = 0
        df.loc[i, group_col_name] = group_no
        last_time = t

    df[group_col_name] = df[group_col_name].astype(int)
```

Call the function similarly as follows:

```
assign_groups(df, '1s', 'Group_ID')     # for 1 second max_time_gap
```

**Result:**

**New column of `Group_ID` at the right of the dataframe.**

```
print(df)

   clients  connections  grants    bytes  updates  writes                  timestamp  Group_ID
0        0        12333   322.0  23323.0   2433.0  6543.0 2019-04-18 21:06:07.260973         1
1      122         8777   766.0   4556.0   8755.0   766.4 2019-04-18 21:06:07.344215         1
2      655        75566  4567.0   9877.6     56.6   778.0 2019-04-18 21:06:07.436656         1
3      454          453    32.5   4553.0    344.0  3422.0 2019-04-18 21:06:07.525223         1
4     3222          113   342.0   5644.0   4566.0   233.3 2019-04-18 21:06:09.622103         2
5     3122          113    42.0   2644.0   4536.0   333.3 2019-04-18 21:06:10.622103         2
6     3222          133   342.0   5644.0   4516.0   133.3 2019-04-18 21:06:10.862103         3
```